# 2D JComboBox that one controling items of the other with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jcombobox

I'm stuck on making two dropdown menus in Java GUI Form that the selection of first one will determine the choices in the second menu.

What I hope to achieve looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPt4p.png)

And after I switched my choice in comboBox1, it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPPUi.png)

Here's my tester code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tester tester = new Tester();
        String[] flower = {"Rose", "Tulip"};
        String[] color1 = {"Yellow", "Blue", "Red"};
        String[] color2 = {"Purple", "White", "Green"};

        for (String flowerPicked : flower) {
            tester.comboBox1.addItem(flowerPicked);
        }
        tester.comboBox1.addActionListener(e -> {
            // remove previous items in comboBox2 everytime a new item in box1 is selcted
            tester.comboBox2.removeAllItems();
            String flowerChoice = tester.comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (flowerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rose"))
                for (String colorPicked : color1) {
                    tester.comboBox2.addItem(colorPicked );
                }
            else
                for (String type : color2) {
                    tester.comboBox2.addItem(type);
                }
        });    
        tester.comboBox2.addActionListener(e -> {
            String colorChoice = tester.comboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String flowerChoice = tester.comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            system.out.println(colorChoice + " " + flowerChoice);
        });
    }
```

But I always run into NullPointerException at removeAllItems() and comboBox2.getSelectedItems() everytime I try to switch my choice in comboBox1.

I tried to debug it, but it seems it's because actionListener of comboBox2 was called whenever the program did removeAllItems() and comboBox2.addItem(). And I don't know how to handle this

A little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that removing all items from the JComboBox causes its ActionListener to fire and to return selection of null.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove all ActionListeners from the JComboBox before removing all items, and then replace the listeners when done.  -- or --
2. Don't call `toString()` on the item returned (that's what throws the NPE -- calling `toString()` on a null reference) but rather cast the selected item returned as a String. A cast won't throw the NPE.

Example of the first:

```
ActionListener[] actionListeners = tester.comboBox2.getActionListeners();
for (ActionListener actionListener : actionListeners) {
    tester.comboBox2.removeActionListener(actionListener);
}
tester.comboBox2.removeAllItems();
String flowerChoice = tester.comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (flowerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rose"))
    for (String colorPicked : color1) {
        tester.comboBox2.addItem(colorPicked);
    }
else {
    for (String type : color2) {
        tester.comboBox2.addItem(type);
    }
}
for (ActionListener actionListener : actionListeners) {
    tester.comboBox2.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
```

Example of the second:

```
String colorChoice = (String) tester.comboBox2.getSelectedItem();
String flowerChoice = (String) tester.comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(colorChoice + " " + flowerChoice);
```